# Redirect to another URL after submitting a form - Mobile version

Tags: 2013, list, newform

I have used the Source querystring (http:///Lists/Test/NewItem.aspx?Source=http:///SitePages/Thankyou.aspx) parameter to redirect users to a specific page after submitting a new item.

This is functioning correctly when using browser on a PC/Laptop.
However when accessing the form using a mobile device, the user is redirected to all Items (List) when submitting the form. This redirection is not functioning on mobile devices.

Any hints/ideas please?